# two users conversation URL in php mysqli

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am creating two users conversation view script in PHP mysqli. my script if of the another users last message it URL opening, but when I sent as a last message, it not open, because it showing my id, therefor 
I want to get  another users id to URL without my id,

Sorry for my bad English.

My database pm table

```
id  from_id    to_id     msg               sent_date
1   2          3         hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20
2   3          2         fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58
3   2          3         hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34
4   5          2         hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40
```

Url

```
<a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php echo $row['from_id'];?">Replay</a>
```

Here is my source code

```
  <?php
    require_once"config.php";
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $to_id = $_SESSION['userid'];  
    }

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ?  ORDER BY sent_time DESC")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $to_id, $to_id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $tempArray = array();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          if (!in_array($row['to_id'].$row['from_id'], $tempArray)) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['from_id']." - " . $row['to_id']." ". $row['msg']. " - " .$row['sent_time'];


    ?>

 <a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php echo $row['from_id'];?">Replay</a>

    <?php }?>
    <?php


          array_push($tempArray, $row['from_id'].$row['to_id']);
          array_push($tempArray, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

        }
    } else {
        echo "NO MESSAGES";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: unable to understand ;). what you want to say here

Comment: you can tell me your points to me using hindi, or hinglish language.

Comment: Whose ID do you want to get in the href?

Comment: when i discussed another user last message if have sent i cant not open coversation becource it showing my id therefor i want get another user it to url

Comment: my problem when i sent last message not open  but another user if the sent me  last message it url open.

Comment: can you please the screen shot of your output. @previn

Comment: i have found a small mistake in your code.

Comment: I have updated two output image

Comment: where you have declare the `$to_id="something"` variable.

Comment: you are selecting the data from the database where `from_id = $to_id and to_id = $to_id`
`$stmt->bind_param('ii', $to_id, $to_id);`

check the code

Comment: like this message display Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\npm\cons.php on line 76
NO MESSAGE

Comment: display no message word

Comment: @Jonathan Thunberg can you help me bro

Comment: coz, you haven't declare the `$from_id` variable yet.

Comment: oops a single mistake you were making

Comment: i added not showing anything

Comment: wait let me post the full answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope I understood this time

Here is my code:

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
  }

  if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ? ORDER BY sent_date DESC")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $session_id, $session_id);
    $stmt->execute();
  }

  $tempArray = array();

  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if (!in_array($row['to_id'].$row['from_id'], $tempArray)) {

          echo "<br>";
          echo $row['from_id']." - " . $row['to_id']." ". $row['msg']. " - " .$row['sent_time'];


        $guaranteed_from_id = str_replace($session_id, null, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

        ?>

        <a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php echo $guaranteed_from_id ?>">Replay</a>

        <?php

 }


        array_push($tempArray, $row['from_id'].$row['to_id']);
        array_push($tempArray, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

      }
  } else {
      echo "NO MESSAGES";
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203864/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-thunberg-two-users-conversation-url-in-php-mysq).

Answer (score 0):

make a change in your URL also.

```
<a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php if(isset($_GET['to_id'])) {$to_id=$_GET['to_id']; echo $to_id;}?>">Replay</a>
```

use this code.

```
<?php
    require_once"config.php";
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $from_id = $_SESSION['userid'];  
    }
    if (isset($_GET['to_id'])) {
    $to_id= $_GET['to_id'];  
    }

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ?  ORDER BY sent_time DESC")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $from_id, $to_id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $tempArray = array();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          if (!in_array($row['to_id'].$row['from_id'], $tempArray)) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['from_id']." - " . $row['to_id']." ". $row['msg']. " - " .$row['sent_time'];


    ?>

 <a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php echo $row['from_id'];?">Replay</a>

    <?php }?>
    <?php


          array_push($tempArray, $row['from_id'].$row['to_id']);
          array_push($tempArray, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

        }
    } else {
        echo "NO MESSAGES";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: same results getting

Comment: you can reply of your own message, but you can't reply to the opposite sender's message.
is it your problem?

Comment: i am too confused, can you mail us your code at info@socialcodia.com

Comment: my code problem, when i disucssed with other user, if i have sent message as a last message it  my user id display on the url, but i want discussed other user id to get url
MY id 1 you can check output image

Comment: i checked brother but same results

Comment: mail me your full code if you can. at socialcodia@gmail.com

Comment: from_id one problem i have when i sent last message another user if the sent me the message as a last message it url opening problem when i sent last message it display my userid that'why problem